# How to change Sybase ASE page size and charset?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, page-size

I've a Sybase ASE server that has 2k page size and the charset is roman8.
I want to change it to a 8k page sizeserver with charset utf8.

Is it possibler to do it without migrating the data to a new server?
If so, what are the commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change page size, the only option is to migrate data to a new database either with sybmigrate available in your ASE installation ($HOME/ASE-15_0/bin/sybmigrate) or by bcp in/out all your tables to the new database.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve logical page size & server charset changes, you need to do the followings:-

(1) install a new ASE server with logical page size of 8K on the same host or new host machine;
(2) Use sybmigrate binary from the new 8K-server installation path (look under $SYBASE/ASE_15-0/bin) & following the new ASE version's online doc pages (on What sybmigrate does & What sybmigrate does not do) NOTE - you need to set up the new ASE installation's SYBASE environment then create $SYBASEOLD environmental variable to point to your 2K-server;
(3) After all the databases have been migrated to the new 8K-server, following the hints & tips in this SAP whitepaper to change the server charset from ROMAN8 to UTF8

> http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-42436